# how to create a data file with a column of date from day1 to dayN?

Tags: text-processing, awk, date, columns

I was wondering if I could generate a hourly or daily time step date in a column starting from some year in the past to some day in the near past or today. 
to be more clear, I want to create one column of data from 2000-10-10 100 to 2012-12-31 2400. The output file will look like

```
Date 

2000-01-01 100
2000-01-01 200
2000-01-01 300
.
.
.
.
.
2012-12-31 2400
```

Comment: Without knowing the flow of your data I'm guessing you want something like `echo "$(date +%F) 100 2000" >> somefile` Please explain your question so people could answer the question.

Comment: Note that the second after `2012-12-31 235959` is generally expressed as `2013-01-01 000000`, not `2012-12-31 240000`.

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/bin/bash

day=2000-01-01
end=2012-12-31

echo Date > output.file

until [[ $day > $end ]]; do
    printf "$day %d\n" $(seq 100 100 2400)
    day=$(date -d "$day + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
done >> output.file
```

Comment: How is that comparison working? Is it just a byte-by-byte character comparison or does bash actually parse and interpret the date strings?

Comment: It's just a lexical (string) comparison: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Answer (score 3):

With `ksh93`:

```
d1=$(printf '%(%s)T\n' "2000-01-01 01:00:00")
d2=$(printf '%(%s)T\n' "2013-01-01 00:00:00")
for ((d=d1;d<d2;d+=3600)); do
  printf '%(%F %-H%M)T\n' "#$d"
done
```

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime -rs d1 '%Y%m%d%H%M' 201201010100
strftime -rs d2 '%Y%m%d%H%M' 201301010000
for ((d=d1;d<d2;d+=3600)) strftime '%F %-H%M' $d
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le '
  $d1=mktime 0,0,1,1,0,100;$d2=mktime 0,0,0,1,0,113;
  for ($d=$d1; $d<$d2; $d+=3600) {
    print strftime "%F %-H%M", localtime $d}'
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {d1=mktime("2000 01 01 01 00 00")
            d2=mktime("2013 01 01 00 00 00")
            for (d=d1;d<d2;d+=3600)
              print strftime("%F %-H%M",d)}'
```

Note that with all the above around DST changing time some hours will be skipped or output twice if in a timezone with DST as a clock would.

We're counting from 000 to 2300 instead of 100 to 2400.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has some error while running. Here is the error awk: line 5: function strftime never defined
awk: line 5: function mktime never defined
awk: line 5: function mktime never defined

Comment: @Abraham - double check it, I just copy/pasted it into a terminal and it ran fine.

Comment: @Stephane -I don't know, it is still not working for me. The same error massage.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN {d1=mktime("2000 01 01 01 00 00")
            d2=mktime("2013 01 01 00 00 00")
            for (d=d1;d<d2;d+=3600)
              print strftime("%F %-H%M",d)}'

Comment: @Abraham, as I said, you need _GNU_ awk. That's GNU specific, it won't work with any other awk.

Comment: @Abraham, from your error message, yours is probably `mawk` which you can verify by running `awk -W version`. There may be a `gawk` command on your system for GNU awk.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has gotten more understandable, the following little script could do something similar.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
c=100

while ((c>i))
    do
    echo "$(date +%F)" $c >> thisfile
    sleep 5
    echo "$(date +%F)" $((c+=100))
    done
```

I hope it's self explanatory

I've used a `sleep 5` but to get exactly this line each hour generated you can use something like `sleep $((60*60))`

Comment: first I want to thank you. I run the script and have seen the result. The problem was, it didn't go to the next day after 24 hours, rather in just starts from today at 100 and continue to nX100 for the same day. What I want is generate a date data file, hourly time step, the starting from January 2000 at 100 hour, to December 2012 at 2400 hour. Thank you!