# How to print dates between two different dates

Tags: ksh, date

I want to print dates between 2 different dates (i.e. start date and two dates)

If start date is `2013-09-05` and end date is `2013-09-10`, then I want result as

```
2013-09-05
2013-09-06
2013-09-07
2013-09-08
2013-09-09 
2013-09-10
```

..... etc

During month end and month start, it should print correct dates.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the `date` command. In the UNIX world, dates are measured in [seconds since the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). If you convert your dates to seconds, you can use `date` to print out the ones you are interested in:

```
END=$(date -d "2013-09-10" +%s);
DATE=$(date -d "2013-09-05" +%s); 
while [[ "$DATE" -le "$END" ]]; do date -d "@$DATE" +%F; let DATE+=86400; done
```

Copy/pasting that into your terminal should return

```
2013-09-05
2013-09-06
2013-09-07
2013-09-08
2013-09-09
2013-09-10
```

The relevant sections of `man date`:

```
   -d, --date=STRING
          display time described by STRING, not 'now'

   %F     full date; same as %Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: Note that in the _Unix world_, `date` doesn't take a `-d` option (or when it does it's not always for that). In the GNU world, it does though, but the `ksh` tag suggests the OP's is more likely to be in a Unix than GNU world.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas ok, thanks. Any ideas on how to do this without `-d`? The only thing I said about the Unix world was that dates are expressed in seconds since the epoch, I did not mean to imply that the Unix `date` can take `-d`.

Comment: A few options [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88599/22565)

Comment: @user48204 what operating system do you have? StephaneChazelas points out above that `-d` is a GNU specific flag.

Comment: Hi, i am getting below error ;  Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
./bkdt.sh[13]: DATE+=86400: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.
date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
./bkdt.sh[13]: DATE+=86400: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.
date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"].   Kindly suggest.

Comment: @user48204 see my last comment, what it your OS and what does `date --version` print? If you don't have GNU date, you are probably going to have to write a script using date manipulation libraries. Also, see the link provided in Stephane's comment.

Comment: Hi,,i am using AIX 7.1 / KSH: Version M-11/16/88f            this is my script       
#!/bin/ksh
date1='20120601'
date2='20120614'
u1=`echo $date1|cut -c1-4|tr -d ' '``echo $date1|cut -c5-6|tr -d ' '``echo $date1|cut -c7-8|tr -d ' '`
u2=`echo $date2|cut -c1-4|tr -d ' '``echo $date2|cut -c5-6|tr -d ' '``echo $date2|cut -c7-8|tr -d ' '`
fmt=""
while (( u1 < u2 )) do  printf "%s%(%Y%m%d)T" "$fmt" "#$u1"
    (( u1 += 3600*24 ))
    fmt=", "
done printf "\n"  . Here while loop is not working. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra details rather than posting comments. Also, if you want to ask about a new issue, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -A5 "2013-09-05" file
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/2013-09-05/,/2013-09-10/{print}' file
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/2013-09-05/,/2013-09-10/p' file
```

Or, reading the comment, using GNU `date`:

```
start=2013-09-05 
end=2013-09-11
   while [[ $start < $end ]] 
     do 
      printf "$start\n"; start=$(date -d "$start + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d") 
     done
```

Comment: Don't know that the OP has a file with all the dates in them. I got the distinct impression he's looking to be able to input a date range and have all dates in the range generated

Comment: @1_CR. Well if none of these would help, then I'm out of options.